# How customized can an Area51 site be?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, stack-exchange, facebook

My specific question is, could we add Facebook Connect as a requirement for users of

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7285/facebook-developers

so the site could then do fancy things like

- show the result of sample graph API calls
- auto-fill in your fb apps
- show a list of how many users use your FB apps (for a quick karma-like score)

Answer (score 5):

Making participation in a SE site depend on membership of a third party site is just icky (beyond your OpenID provider of choice, which you can become yourself). Beyond a tacit endorsement of the third party site/service, its more merge conflicts when the SE site has to be updated.

There may be experts who can contribute something who just got fed up with FB and deleted their accounts, I don't see why they should be squelched.

If the powers that be are willing to codify your request, great :) But graceful fall back is needed, and we're again delving into sites running variants of SE software that are sufficiently diverse to present an interesting path to mass upgrade issues.

Additionally, some people might not want that information shown or even stored, for whatever reason.

Comment: True. I was just wondering if it's possible (for example, mathoverflow includes a javascript library for latex). I don't think it would be mandatory, but it would help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a FB person, so I wouldn't use the FB Developers SE, and if I was required to connect a FB account, I wouldn't.  If that meant not answering a question that I would otherwise be able to answer [1], so be it, I wouldn't answer it.

That said, I think Paul has a valid interest in wanting the ability to link a FB account to a FB Developers SE account.  Which leads me to wonder if there's a middle ground approach, where the accounts can be linked, but users aren't required to do so?

[1]: Granted, the likelihood that I would actually be able to answer a FB developers question is so slim it approaches 0.